Get workstation list from multiple domains & sort by name, export by name
Currently scanning multiple specific OU's in multiple domains from AD.  I have this code set to scan for pc names & export it to various csv files based on specific name filters.  I use these lists for other tasks.
Primarily, I'd like to export sorted by name (often named by building / dept / floor or type - such as BLDGA3Fxxxx, BLDGB4Fxxxxx, HR2Fxxxxx, xxxxKIOSK,  etc)
Secondarily, would be great to be able to export to separate files by partial name - NameFilter1.csv, NameFilter2.csv, Etc.
Anyone able to assist on this?
$OUs = 'OU=WORKSTATION,DC=domain1,DC=rootdomain,DC=com','OU=WORKSTATION,DC=domain2,DC=rootdomain,DC=com','OU=WORKSTATION,DC=domain3,DC=rootdomain,DC=com'
$domains = "domain1","domain2","domain3"
$exportfiles = "Computer_ALL.txt", "Computer_Name1.txt", "Computer_Name2.txt", "Computer_name3.txt", "Computer_name4.txt"
$Filters =  '*', '*NameFilter1*', 'NameFilter2*', '*NameFilter3', 'NameFilter4*'

foreach ($filter in $filters) {
# Loop through OU & domain simultaneously and get ALL workstations
        $c = 0
        write-host $filter
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $OUs.Count; $i++) {
        write-host "Scanning All Workstations in $($OUs[$i]) on $($domains[$i])..." -BackgroundColor DarkCyan
        Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -notlike 'VDI-*' -and Name -notlike 'VM-*' -and Name -notlike 'HOS-*' -and Name -like $Filter} -SearchBase $($OUs[$i]) -Server $($domains[$i]) | ForEach-Object  {
        #Write-Host ($_.Name + "  ---  " + $_.DistinguishedName) 
        $_.Name | Out-File -LiteralPath $($exportfiles[$n]) -Append
        $c++
    }
    }

    write-host "$c total $filter pc's found. Saved to" $($exportfiles[$n]) -BackgroundColor DarkCyan
     write-host " "
    $n++
}


